# Meaning of a Simultaneous Measurement of Spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I am a bit confused about what a simultaneous measurement really means, how we indicate it in spin states, and it's relating to collapsing the state. Let us say I have a two spin state system defined as:

$$| \phi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( | + -\rangle - | -+ \rangle)$$

If I say "a measurement of the first electron spin reveals a value of $\hbar/2$" for $S_{1z}$. What does this tell me about the actual state after the measurement? If I apply $S_{1z} \otimes I $ to $| + -\rangle$ I will get $\hbar /2$. For the other, $| - + \rangle$ I will get $-\hbar/2$. So I know this implies that the state is now $| + -\rangle$. This question confirms this argument: [Spin state of electron after measurement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94549/spin-state-of-electron-after-measurement)

Second, what if I simultaneously measure $S_{2z}$ during this measurement, and I know that $S_{1z}$ resulted in $\hbar / 2$. Can I say anything about what $S_{2z}$ measurement was? When we say "total spin in the z component $S_{z}^{total}$" is that equivalent to $S_{1z} \otimes S_{2z}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in saying that if the measurement of $S_z$ was found to be $+\hbar/2$ on the first particle as subsequent measurement of $S_z$ on the second particle will yield $-\hbar/2$ - that is why this state is sometimes called the perfectly anti-correlated state.

Your question is a bit confusing regarding time. If you say you measure $S_z$ on both particles, the results will be perfectly anti-correlated. So if you know the first particle was in state "up", you will know that the second particle was in state "down".

Regarding the total angular momentum $S_z^{\text{total}}$, it is not given by the tensor product of $S_{z} \otimes S_{z}$.
Instead, the total angular momentum along the $z$-axis is given by the sum: $$S_z^{\text{total}} = S_z \otimes I + I \otimes S_z$$
Note that $⟨S_z^{\text{total}}⟩ = 0$ for the singlet state (as it should be).

Furthermore, the operator you wrote down is already diagonal
$$S_{z} \otimes S_{z} 
= \frac{\hbar^2}{4} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & & &\\ & -1 & &\\ & & -1 &\\ & & & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

You can see that it has degenerate eigenvalues $+\frac{\hbar^2}{4}$ and $-\frac{\hbar^2}{4}$. Where the eigenstates of for example $-\frac{\hbar^2}{4}$ are $|+-⟩$ and $|-+⟩$ and therefore also any linear combination of the two. A measurement of $S_{z} \otimes S_{z}$ can therefore not distinguish between those states.

As note, just to generalize that, you can show that measuring the spin along different axis for both particles, let's say along direction $\vec{a}$ for the first and along $\vec{b}$ for the second (where $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are unit vectors), will give an expectation value (in the singlet state) of:
$$⟨\vec{S}\cdot \vec{a} \otimes \vec{S}\cdot \vec{b}⟩ = -\frac{\hbar^2}{4}\;\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} $$
This is important for the famous Bell inequalities, see the original: [J.S. Bell, On the Einstein Podolsky Rosen Paradox, Physics Vol. I, 1964] or simply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem.

Lastly, it is important to point out that a measurement of $S_z$ on the second particle without any knowledge of the first particle, will still have a random outcome (a 50/50 chance to get spin up or down). Assume Alice measures the first and Bob the second particle, if Bob does not communicate/or even know anything about Alice, his results are always random, regardless of Alice's measurements (which are of course random as well). However, if they compare their results afterwards, they will find the perfectly anti-correlated pattern.
I hope this helps!

Comment: the OP might be trying to trap the electrons by measuring the spin at exactly the same time instant (if relativisticly possible). How does one electron know to take on the opposite spin if the spin is measured at the exact same instant for both the electrons?